# EF Core Relation doesn't exist

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I want to create a database in PostgreSQL and API for my app. I've created Model and API in EF Core 1.0.0. Model exists in separate library.

```
public class Architect : IEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}

public class Project : IEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(IsoDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProjectState> ProjectStates { get; set; }
    public Guid ArchitectId { get; set; }
    public Architect Architect { get; set; }
}

public class Company : IEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
}

 public class ProjectState : IEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ProjectPhase phase { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

I have created also DemoContext that inherits DbContext. I defined relashionships in OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) method.

```
public class DemoContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Architect> Architects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProjectState> ProjectStates { get; set; }

    public DemoContext(DbContextOptions<DemoContext> options) : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("PORT = 5432; HOST = localhost; TIMEOUT = 15; POOLING = True; MINPOOLSIZE = 1; MAXPOOLSIZE = 20; COMMANDTIMEOUT = 20; DATABASE = ProgressTest; PASSWORD = 'postgres'; USER ID = postgres", b => b.MigrationsAssembly("WebAPI.API"));
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasPostgresExtension("uuid-ossp");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Architect)
            .WithMany(a => a.Projects)
            .HasForeignKey(p=>p.ArchitectId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectState>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Project)
            .WithMany(p => p.ProjectStates)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.ProjectId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>()
            .HasOne(c => c.Project)
            .WithMany(p => p.Companies)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ProjectId);
    }
}
```

I want to migrate all classes and create new database. I've used
*dotnet ef migrations add InitializeMigration* to add new migration and after it I wanted to update my database, so I've used *dotnet ef database update* but Postgres throw an Exception:

```
Npgsql.PostgresException: 42P01: relationship "ProjectState.IX_ProjectState_ProjectId" doesn't exist
```

Can you help me with it?

Comment: This doesn't happen when testing your code against Sqlite. Try adding the migration again with the `-script` switch to see what the generated DDL is like. Then execute it against the database directly.

Comment: I have no idea what happened, but after generate -script from my migration, I used *database update* and the database has been created without problems. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 3):

In my case i just decorate my model class with "Table" attribute with actual table name (mind case sensativity) and it resolved my problem

```
[Table("city")]
public class CityModel
```

Comment: Same here, thanks for posting!